# Form validation in angularjs doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, validation

I wrote a form validation in angularjs but it does not work.

When I send form with empty fields form has class 'ng-valid' and 'ng-hide' doesn't remove from error.

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="createUser(user)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nazwa użytkownika:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" ng.model="user.name" required="">
        <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.name.$touched">
            <div ng-show="form.name.$error.required">Podaj nazwę użytkownika.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Adres e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng.model="user.email">
        <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.email.$touched">
            <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required">Podaj adres e-mail.</span>
            <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email">Adres e-mail jest nieprawidłowy.</span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role">Rola użytkownika:</label>
        <select name="role" id="role" class="form-control" ng-model="user.role">
            <option value="3">klient</option>
            <option value="2">pracownik</option>
            <option value="3">admin</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.role.$touched">
            <span ng-show="form.role.$error.required">Wybierz rolę użytkownika.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj użytkownika</button
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in some of your `ng-model`. It should be `ng-model` instead of `ng.model`. You have to set `ng-required="true"` or you can simply put `required` across all your mandatory fields

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true">
```

Comment: `ng-model` not `ng.model`

Comment: And `required=""` does not make a difference. `required="" or ng-required="true"` or `required` works just fine.

Comment: Yes I know but the OP hasn't put required="" across all mandatory fields